# How do I programmatically determine the resource limits available in the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, resources

Is it possible to programatically determine the resource limits of the JVM? I am trying to determine what percentage of resources a particular process consumes of what is available.
I know that there are lots of tools out there such as jconsole to do this but I need to do it in the code and I haven't come across anything to do this. From other reading the number of available threads  will determined by the hardware, the application is not suing a fixed threadpool.
I was then going to use the ThreadMXBean to determine how many threads a particular process is using and calculate a percentage based on this.

Comment: These may come in handy : `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();` and `MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();` 
    `memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();`

Comment: What resource limits are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
long mTotalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
int mAvailableProcessors = runtime.availableProcessors();

long mTotalFreeMemory = freeMemory + (maxMemory - mTotalMemory);
```